# Adding a field to a nested document in mongoDB node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello since there is not subcollections in mongodb i have found that you can nest document as an array ! i did that and it worked but what i want is to add a field to that existing array without losing the old ones ! i can do that by fetching the old array and adding the new field to it and returning that array but doing the fetch inside the patch method wouldn't be a good approach ! so is there any other way i can make that happen ?

Modal :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    notificationType: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    message: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  passwordHash: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  street: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  notifications: [notificationSchema],
  apartment: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  zip: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
});

exports.User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
exports.Notification = mongoose.model("Notification", notificationSchema);
```

```
router.patch("/:id", async (req, res) => {
 try {

   console.log("hh");
   const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
     notifications: [
       {
         notificationType: "Order",
         message: "New Notification",
       },
     ],
   });
   if (!user) {
     return res.status(404).send("The user cannot be found");
   }

   res.send(user);
 } catch (error) {
   return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error });
 }
});
```

Comment: Seems like you want to `"$push"` a new object to the `"notifications"` array.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what im looking for ! Thank you so much sir